# Joomla Login Redirect

Tags: php, joomla

How can you specify which page the user lands after they have logged into a Joomla site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through the Login Redirection Page in the Parameters section of the Login Module, or the Login Redirection URL Parameter in the link to the Default Login Layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an authentication plugin that hooks into the necessary events and sets the location header for the redirect.

- [Tutorial:Creating an Authentication Plugin for Joomla 1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5)